# Googleドライブの各フォルダのメンバー情報をスプシに一覧表示させたい

Tags: google-apps-script

●実現したいこと
Goolgeドライブの各フォルダの下記情報をスプシに表示させたいです。
・共有ドライブ
・メンバー
・メール
・タイプ
・役割

●現状
「メンバー」と「メール」の項目のみブランクのままです。
[![画像の説明をここに入力][1]][1]

●コード

```
const act_sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
let drv_list, drv_info, drv_token;
let prm_list, prm_info, role_ja;
let array = [];

function myFunction() {
  array.push(["共有ドライブ", "メンバー", "メール", "タイプ", "役割"]);

  // Drive APIから共有ドライブのリストを取得、pageTokenがある限り繰り返し
  do {
    drv_list = Drive.Drives.list({
      maxResults: 300,
      pageToken: drv_token,
      useDomainAdminAccess: true
    });

    for (let i = 0; i < drv_list.drives.length
  ; i++) {
      drv_info = drv_list.drives[i];
    

      try {
          // 共有ドライブごとにパーミッション情報を取得
        prm_list = Drive.Permissions.list(
          drv_info.id,
          {supportsAllDrives: true, useDomainAdminAccess: true}
        );
      
        for (let j = 0; j < prm_list.permissions.length; j++) {
          prm_info = prm_list.permissions[j];

          // ロール情報を日本語化
          switch (prm_info.role) {
            case ("organizer"):
              role_ja = "管理者";
              break;
            case ("fileOrganizer"):
              role_ja = "コンテンツ管理者";
              break;
            case ("reader"):
              role_ja = "閲覧者";
              break;
            case ("commenter"):
              role_ja = "閲覧者（コメント可）";
              break;
            case ("writer"):
              role_ja = "投稿者";
              break;
            default:
              role_ja = prm_info.role;
          }

          // 取得した共有ドライブ名および各種情報を配列に追加
          if (j === 0) {
            array.push([
              drv_info.name, 
              prm_info.displayName, prm_info.emailAddress, prm_info.type, role_ja
            ]);
          } else {
            array.push([
              "",  // 出力形式上、最初のメンバー以外の配列には共有ドライブ名不要
              prm_info.displayName, prm_info.emailAddress, prm_info.type, role_ja
            ]);
          }
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        array.push([err]);
        continue;
      }
    }
    drv_token = drv_list.nextPageToken;
  } while (drv_token);

  // 配列をGoogleシートに反映
  act_sheet.clear();
  act_sheet.setFrozenRows(1);
  act_sheet.getRange(1, 1, array.length, array[0].length).setValues(array);
}
```

●試したこと
原因が全くわからず、、下記コードのdisplayNameをnameに変更したり、emailAddressをemailに変更したりしましたが結果は当然変わらず。
prm_info.displayName, prm_info.emailAddress,

何かご存知の方ご教授願います！！

Comment: [他のサイトでも同じ内容の投稿](https://teratail.com/questions/0smkktwjhqkpzz) をされているようですが、予め質問の本文にその旨を明示しておいてもらうとスムーズに回答が付きやすくなると思います。 / 参考: [マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418)

Answer (score 0):

#### 修正箇所

- スクリプトを見ますと、Drive APIのv2とv3が混在しているようです。現状セクションの`「メンバー」と「メール」の項目のみブランクのままです。`から、実行できているとのことですので、Drive API v3を有効にして実行していると推測します。
- `Drive.Drives.list`について、`maxResults`はDrive API v2で使用されます。今の場合、リクエストでは`maxResults: 300`を無視して実行されるためエラーが発生しないと思われます。また、この場合、最大値は100のようです。このため、`maxResults: 300`は、`pageSize: 100`として修正するとよろしいかと思われます。
- `Drive.Permissions.list`について、Drive API v3の場合、デフォルトでのリクエストでは全てのfieldsを返しません。このため、fieldsを設定する必要があります。今の場合、`fields: "*"`でよろしいかと思われます。

これらを表示されているスクリプトへ反映させますと、次のようなスクリプトではいかがでしょうか。修正箇所へ`// <--- Modified`を追記しました。

#### 修正したスクリプト

```js
const act_sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
let drv_list, drv_info, drv_token;
let prm_list, prm_info, role_ja;
let array = [];

function myFunction() {を
  array.push(["共有ドライブ", "メンバー", "メール", "タイプ", "役割"]);

  // Drive APIから共有ドライブのリストを取得、pageTokenがある限り繰り返し
  do {
    drv_list = Drive.Drives.list({
      pageSize: 100, // <--- Modified
      pageToken: drv_token,
      useDomainAdminAccess: true
    });

    for (let i = 0; i < drv_list.drives.length
      ; i++) {
      drv_info = drv_list.drives[i];


      try {
        // 共有ドライブごとにパーミッション情報を取得
        prm_list = Drive.Permissions.list(
          drv_info.id,
          { supportsAllDrives: true, useDomainAdminAccess: true, fields: "*" } // <--- Modified
        );

        for (let j = 0; j < prm_list.permissions.length; j++) {
          prm_info = prm_list.permissions[j];

          // ロール情報を日本語化
          switch (prm_info.role) {
            case ("organizer"):
              role_ja = "管理者";
              break;
            case ("fileOrganizer"):
              role_ja = "コンテンツ管理者";
              break;
            case ("reader"):
              role_ja = "閲覧者";
              break;
            case ("commenter"):
              role_ja = "閲覧者（コメント可）";
              break;
            case ("writer"):
              role_ja = "投稿者";
              break;
            default:
              role_ja = prm_info.role;
          }

          // 取得した共有ドライブ名および各種情報を配列に追加
          if (j === 0) {
            array.push([
              drv_info.name,
              prm_info.displayName, prm_info.emailAddress, prm_info.type, role_ja
            ]);
          } else {
            array.push([
              "",  // 出力形式上、最初のメンバー以外の配列には共有ドライブ名不要
              prm_info.displayName, prm_info.emailAddress, prm_info.type, role_ja
            ]);
          }
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        array.push([err]);
        continue;
      }
    }
    drv_token = drv_list.nextPageToken;
  } while (drv_token);

  // 配列をGoogleシートに反映
  act_sheet.clear();
  act_sheet.setFrozenRows(1);
  act_sheet.getRange(1, 1, array.length, array[0].length).setValues(array);
}
```

- これを実行してみますと、メンバーやそれぞれのメールアドレスもSpreadsheetへ挿入されることを確認しました。
- このスクリプトは、Drive API v3がAdvanced Google servicesで有効になっていることが前提です。
- `useDomainAdminAccess`を使用する場合は、アカウントが管理者である必要があります。ご注意ください。

#### References:

- [Method: drives.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/drives/list)
- [Method: permissions.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/permissions/list)

Comment: Tanaikeさん☺
ご丁寧な解説ありがとうございます！
おかげさまで、全ての項目が表示されました！

Comment: @goma ご返事ありがとうございます。`おかげさまで、全ての項目が表示されました！`から、無事解決したようで安心しました。